# Insert an item to the last but one position in list

Tags: python, list

I have a list and i want to insert an item to the last but one position

```
list1 = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
list1.insert(-2,'item2.5')
```

but instead of

```
list1 = ['item1', 'item2', 'item2.5', 'item3']
```

I got

```
list1=['item1', 'item2.5', 'item2', 'item3']
```

Is there a way how the code would look as I want to?

Comment: you are giving a wrong index -2 means before two elements from the last, -1 will mean before 1 element from the last. -1 will give you the desired result

Comment: @Inder it works, thanks

Comment: That position has a name - [penultimate](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/penultimate).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to use slicing:

```
>>> list1 = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
>>> list1[-1:-1] = ['item2.5']
>>> list1
['item1', 'item2', 'item2.5', 'item3']
```

Here, you replace the (empty) sub-list `list1[-1:-1]` by a new list `['item2.5']`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add 1 to your argument. It specifies the index to insert BEFORE.